# asp.net image upload

Tags: asp.net, image, upload

i want to upload images of customer in my web application. is there any naming convention should i follow to name the files(e.g; i can store cust_id.jpg or cust_name.jpg). which is better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each customer is to be permitted no more than one image then it would make sense intuitively to use whatever unique identifier the system otherwise uses for that customer, be it a name or a friendly ID or a GUID.  That way it's more immediately recognizable for its relation to the customer data.

Comment: @Rauf Nicole: You have "accepted" very few answers to your previous questions on this site.  It's considered good practice to accept answers which were correct or at least the most helpful (one per question) in order to encourage more answers.

Comment: string newFileName = txtName.Text.Trim().Replace(' ', '_') + System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()  :)